# Idea of gossiping algorithm

Tags: algorithm, random

I would like to implement gossiping algorithm, where I have some network (I don't know how much nodes will be there available) where each node should communicate only with its random neighbour (at each step randomly generated). I want to find that way a coordinator of the system (every node has its own id and know neighbours). Coordinator is node, which has the biggest id in the network.

I was looking on net for some solution, but I've found nothing. I think the biggest problem is in node, that how to get information, that every node in network has the coordinator id (I should finish).

Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: What is your specific issue ?

Comment: Matt, I think what Dami wants to do is to do a  set up where Gossip algorithm can be simulated. Dami, correct me if i am wrong.